# Python equivalent of Matlab addpath

Tags: python, matlab, directory

Does python have an equivalent to Matlab's addpath?  I know about sys.path.append, but that only seems to work for python files/modules, not for general files.

Suppose I have a file config.txt in C:\Data and the current working directory is something else, say D:\my_project.

I would like to have code similar to:

```
def foo():
    with open('config.txt') as f:
        print(f.read())

def main():
    addpath(r'C:\Data')
    foo()
```

Obviously I could pass the path to foo here, but that is very difficult in the actual use case.

Comment: MATLAB’s `addpath` is **not** to add paths to data files. It works with `load`, so that users can load example data sets that come with a toolbox, but it is not intended for the general use case.  This is bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't.  Python doesn't work this way.  Files are loaded from the current working directory or a specific, resolved path.  There is no such thing as a set of pre-defined paths for loading arbitrary files.

Keeping data and program logic separate is an important concept in Python (and most other programming languages besides MATLAB).  An key principle of python is "Explicit is better than implicit."  Making sure the data file you want to load is defined explicitly is much safer, more reliable, and less error-prone.

So although others have shown how you can hack some workarounds, I would very, very strongly advise you to not use this approach.  It is going to make maintaining your code much harder.

Comment: I am surprised by this.  I always felt that Python errored on the side of being too open and flexible.  Many things in software are often a bad idea but still have very important use cases, Python multiple inheritance and java reflection come to mind.

Comment: Of course, you can do it, as other people have shown.  Python makes it possible to do things that you shouldn't do, but generally makes it difficult.  In Python, if you find you have to jump through a lot of hoops to make something work it is usually a good sign you are doing something you shouldn't be.

Comment: I don't think others have shown how.  I actually want to call "addpath" multiple times, and then several layers down read the files.  I also think its pretty easy to do really bad things in Python, https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2441cv/can_you_change_the_value_of_1/, but note I consider this a strength of the language

Comment: “and most other programming languages besides MATLAB” — This is incorrect. MATLAB likes the separation between data and code just as much as the next language. I have no idea where this comment comes from.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The question were are talking about here is one such instance, where it explicitly treats data and logic as equivalent. But that isn't an isolated example. The language is built around scripts and simple one-off functions. It was only very recently that it provided any support at all for any more structured code than that, and that support is still half-baked. It didn't even provide support for distributing code to others until recently. And it is still inordinately difficult to write general-purpose code without a ton of checks to make sure it is structured just right.

Comment: @TheBlackCat I don’t agree. I wrote a highly complex, large toolbox more than 20 years ago, for MATLAB 5.3. There was no problem distributing it, which we did like all other software are the time was distributed, in a ZIP file. There weren’t any app stores at the time for any platform. It wasn’t harder to structure that code than it was to structure a large library in C. I don’t understand where your criticism comes from, other than not being familiar with MATLAB. There are many things you can criticize MATLAB for, but this is not one of those things.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Again, this whole question is about MATLAB *explicitly* not distinguishing be code and data. MATLAB didn't even have support for functions originally, it was purely a data-processing tool. Tools like Python and Perl got package handling in the 1990's, MATLAB would take another almost 20 years to get it, and it is still worse than python then (e.g. no concept of dependencies).  C and Python had imports/includes since the 1990's, it would take MATLAB another almost 20 years to get it. And packages are still such a mess (e.g. not relative) they often hurt more than they help.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add multiple paths like you would in matlab.

You can use `os.chdir` to change directories, and access files and sub-directories from that directory:

```
import os

def foo():
    with open('config.txt') as f:
        print(f.read())

def main():
    os.chdir(r'C:\Data')
    foo()
```

To manage multiple directories, using a context manager that returns to the previous directory after the expiration of the context works:

```
import contextlib
import os

@contextlib.contextmanager
def working_directory(path):
    prev_cwd = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(path)
    yield
    os.chdir(prev_cwd)

def foo():
    with open('config.txt') as f:
        print(f.read())

def main():
    with working_directory(r'C:\Data'):
        foo()
    # previous working directory
```

Comment: That works if you only want to add a single path, but with Matlab you can add multiple paths, which probably can't be emulated with this approach.

Comment: @user2133814 Well, this could at least help you change paths on the fly with some certainty about where exactly you are on the file system.

Comment: @Moses Koledoye I had the same issue as user2133814 had. Your 'contextlib' idea works well for me. I should live with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os.chdir` functionality along with your own `open` function to check all the paths you want to.

```
class FileOpener(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.paths = []
    def add_path(self, path):
        self.paths.append(path)
    def __open_path(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
        old_path = os.getcwd()
        try:
            os.chdir(path)
            return open(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            pass
        finally:
            os.chdir(old_path)
    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for path in self.paths + [os.getcwd()]:
            f = self.__open_path(path, *args, **kwargs)
            if f is not None:
                return f
        raise IOError("no such file")

my_file_opener = FileOpener()
my_file_opener.add_path("C:/Data")
my_file_opener.add_path("C:/Blah")
my_file_opener.open("some_file") # checks in C:/Data, C:/Blah and then the current working directory, returns the first file named "some_file" that it finds, and raises an IOError otherwise
```

Answer (score 1):

**sorry, I made a mistake.**

I guess you can use this to solve it. (as a stack newbee, I hope it helps)

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'path')
```

Comment: OP said in the question “I know about sys.path.append”, then explains why it is not useful in their specific case. I recommend that you read more than the question title before answering, especially if there already are so many answers.

Comment: T_T, I am sorry. Thanks for your advice and I will be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(prefix):
    path = prefix + 'config.txt'
    with open(path) as f:
        print(f.read())

def main():
    foo(r'C:\Data\')
```

---update----

```
import os

class changeFileDir:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path= os.path.expanduser(path)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.savedPath = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.path)

    def __exit__(self, etype, value, traceback):
        os.chdir(self.savedPath)


with changeFileDir(r'C:\Data'):
    foo()
```

Comment: as I said in the question, that is an obvious solution for this simple case, but is not really possible for the actual use case.  Besides you should use os.path.join